# javac not recognized in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

Hi i'm using an Eclipse for Android; ECLIPSE ADT BUNDLE
i was wondering if i can still use it to create java applications because when i execute a simple program, eg printing text in CMD **javac Welcome1.java**. i get an error of 
**'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

i set the PATH Environment Variables this way

first i created a new System Variable with a Variable : JAVA_HOME with a value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

still under the system variable, inside the Path variable i inserted  " %JAVA_HOME%bin; "

Comment: missing a \ either before the bin or after the jdk1.7.0_45

Comment: Yeah, Greg's right.  It's more standard to leave the \ off the value of `JAVA_HOME`, but to have `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in the path.

Comment: Cool.  Just one more of those curly details that has to be exactly right.  :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
%JAVA_HOME%bin;
```

to

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```